# Error when adding new Activities to the Android Studio Project

Tags: android-studio

I am carrying out a project on Android Studio, but when I try to add a new empty activity to an open project, after the creation when I launch the app on the emulator it closes by itself giving an error message that disappears if I delete the activity created.

I tried to change the name of the activity, or make it some other type and not empty, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Frist you (Synk project and it's not work -go ahead).

01 - Go to the file - invalidate cache and restart.

02 - Clean project and rebuild project.

03 - Update the latest version android studio.